# How do I move some but not all files from one directory to another?

Tags: shell, rename, filenames, cp

I need to move my files from one directory to other. But there is some issues. My file name pattern is like:

```
  apple.0, apple.<n>, n -> {0,1,2,3 ...~ }
```

so `mv apple.*` will not work, because I need to keep apple.0, which is always the active one.

How do I move them with exceptions (in this case, keeping apple.0)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have bash and don't care about also matching files like `apple.not-a-number`, try

```
shopt -s extglob
mv apple.!(0) /new/directory
```

Comment: `bash: !: event not found`

is thrown.

Comment: I am gonna try `ls`, `egrep` and `mv` with pipes.

Comment: That won't quite work, you cannot use the `&&` operator to combine these. First you need to run the `shopt -s extglob` option to set the shell to use extended globing mode, then you can use that glob pattern. The way this answer is formatted the shell tries to do the globing on the command line before any of the commands (including the one about enabling the option) are run.

Comment: @OlgunKaya: This will work and match your files just like you want if you first run `shopt -s extglob` then in any following command or later in your script use that pattern.

Comment: @Caleb Thanks, you are right. I've fixed it but Marcel's answer is still the better one.

Comment: @MarcelG's answer is good, but because of the character class it is limited to single character exclusions. This extended glob pattern can be extended to be multiple-characters as well as other patterns. It's good to know about both.

Comment: If you did want to combine these into a single command and not change the option in your current shell you would need to invoke a sub-shell. `(shopt -s option ; command [...])`

Answer (score 8):

if you're using bash you should be able to use

```
mv apple.[^0]* /other/directory/
```

this will move any files of which the extension does not start with 0 ( "^" at the beginning of [ ] means "not" in bash). If you're sure there's only one character as an ending you could also use

```
mv apple.[^0] /other/directory/
```

and if you have to make sure only files which end in numbers you could use

```
shopt -s extglob
mv apple.@([1-9])*([0-9]) /other/directory/
```

this would not match apple.01 or similar though....

and a last one which should get all the apple files ending in numbers

```
shopt -s extglob
mv apple.*([1-9]|[0-9]+([0-9])) /other/directory/
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't know bash supported regexes. :)

Comment: Technically globs aren't quite normal regex.  The glob `[1-9][0-9]*` will actually match any pattern that begins with two digits in the range 10-99 followed by anything, e.g. 23apples would match.

Comment: I got something mixed up (regex vs. globs/expansions as balki and jw023 point out) :-) the last option does not what I explained it does... so I fixed it with new options based on the solution by jw0123.

Comment: @balki bash and regexes are like husband and wife.

Comment: With `extglob`, you get the power of regexps but in a wildcard syntax. The zsh analog to these bash commands is to use `setopt ksh_glob` instead of `shopt -s extglob`, or to use `setopt extended_glob` then `mv apple.*~apple.0 /other/directory/`.

Answer (score 2):

To be as specific as you want on the file to move and not to move

```
find /source/directory -maxdepth 1 -name "apple.*" ! -name "apple.0" -exec mv {} /new/directory \;
```